# Delphi calling C++Builder function in obj file, errors occured when some functions used from math.h

Tags: c++, delphi, builder

I want to use Delphi 10 Seattle to call a C obj file complied with C++ Builder 10 Seattle.

It succeeds when the C function is simple, eg. `c=a+b`, but it fails when using `sin()` or `cos()` operations.

The following are the codes:

C++Builder code:

```c
#include "using_math.h"
#include <math.h>

double test2(double a)
{
    return sin(a);
}
```

Header file:

```c
double test2(double a);
```

Delphi code:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$L 'using_math.obj'}
{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Errors:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(27): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_sin'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(27): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__turboFloat'
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Project12.dpr(5): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
```

Comment: The unresolved errors are because the Delphi project is not linking to the C library that implements the C functions that are being called (`sin()`, etc). You can't link to an obj file that makes external calls and not also link to the library that satisfies those calls.

Comment: in fact the easiest way to resolve this is to provide an implementation of sin in your delphi code. You also need to implement __turboFloat, do that by using the unit Crtl

Comment: Thanks a lot！Maybe I can implement new sin() with c instead of lib function. But, are there any other solution if I want to call math lib in C.

Comment: Delphi doesn't have math functions?  It seems strange that this is what you are doing to support a basic trig function in a somewhat mainstream language.

Comment: Why are you so keen to implement sin in C code rather than delphi code? What benefit is there to doing so? What are you actually trying to achieve. I guess you know that Delphi's rtl has both sin and cos.

Comment: @paul of course delphi has trig functions in its rtl. Lord knows what asker is trying to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -- Yes, it did seem strange to me that the OP is implementing something that is already supported by the language.

Comment: Anyway, Rudy explains the main techniques here http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html

Comment: @David Heffernan, I got it. The primary purpose is to compile an independent  FFT lib with C, and provide obj or DLL for Delphi invoking. I solved the problem with all your kind help now.Thanks!